# Python: Why would numpy.corrcoef() return NaN values?

Tags: python, numpy

Why would `numpy.corrcoef()` return `NaN` values?

I am working with high dimensional data and it is infeasible to go through every datum to test values.

```
# Import
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Delete all zero columns
df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]

# Delete any NaN columns
df = df.dropna(axis='columns', how='any', inplace=False)

# Standardise
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.values)
print(X_std.dtype) # Returns "float64"

# Correlation
cor_mat1 = np.corrcoef(X_std.T)
cor_mat1.max() # Returns nan
```

And then 
`cor_mat1.max()`

Returns

> nan

When computing `cor_mat1 = np.corrcoef(X_std.T)`  I get this warning:

> /Users/kimrants/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3183:
>   RuntimeWarning:
>
> invalid value encountered in true_divide

This is a snippet of the input dataframe:
[image]

To try and fix it myself, I started removing all zero-columns and columns that contained *any* `NaN` values. I thought this would solve the problem, but it didn't. Am I missing something? I don't see why else it would return `NaN` values?

My end goal is to compute eigen-values and -vectors.

Comment: Could you please share your code using np.corrcoef()? How are you applying it to the matrix?

Comment: How about a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @dportman Please see edited version now.

Comment: @norok2  See above. Thanks.

Comment: This is far from a MVCE (no imports, no data, undefined symbols). Anyway, besides that, what is on `X_std`? Could it be that the first columns forces the numpy array to be of type string (hence preventing `np.corrcoef` from working the way you expect)?

Comment: @norok2 I added more information. 
I don't see why imports are relevant?  Why would the correlation computation divide by zero at any point, do you know?

Comment: can you check the `dtype` of `X_std`. Imports are very relevant because otherwise things like `StandardScaler()` can be anything. Also, the input data is relevant here!

Comment: @norok2 Got it.. thank you for feedback. Type if "float64" and I have uploaded imports

Comment: Do you get all NaN values or just some of them?

Try to apply np.corrcoef() to a small subset of your matrix (10x10) first.

Comment: You should check if you have, for whatever reasons, `np.nan` or `0`-only columns in `X_std`, I believe. Besides that, I would need to provide some data showing the issue, if you want other people to actually being able to solve the problem,

Comment: @norok2 I found that performing: X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.values) followed by
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_std) solves the issue, which seems quite weird? See code below.

Comment: @KimO if that is removing the `0`-only columns I do not think that this is so surprising, but there are probably better ways of doing so..

Comment: @norok2 But shouldn't this happen in the first standardisation?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a column where all rows have the same value, that column's variance is `0`.  `np.corrcoef()` thus numpy-divides that column's correlation coefficients by `0`, which doesn't throw an error but only the warning `invalid value encountered in true_divide` with standard numpy settings. Those column's correlation coefficients get replaced by 'nan' instead:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.divide(0,0))

C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
nan
```

Removing all columns with `Series.nunique() == 1` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for reasons I cannot explain:

```
# Import
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Delete any NaN columns
df = df.dropna(axis='columns', how='any', inplace=False)

# Keep track of index / columns to reproduce dataframe
cols = df.columns
index = df.index

# Standardise
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.values)
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_std)
print(X_std.dtype) # Return "float64"

# Turn to dataFrame again to drop values easier
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X_std, columns= cols, index=index) 

# Delete all zero columns
df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]

# Delete any NaN columns
df = df.dropna(axis='columns', how='any', inplace=False)
```

The standardising two times in a row works, but is weird.